# MediaWiki VisualEditor Extension Not Quite Working

Tags: mediawiki, visual-editor

I've got VisualEditor installed, on a private wiki, with Parsoid running on the same server. I can see the Parsoid activity on the server, and all is well. And the MediaWiki API calls are getting through without trouble.

But when a user clicks the Edit tab on a page, after the page goes a little opaque and the animated progress bar appears, nothing else happens. The WYSIWYG editor never shows up.

This is a Windows installation. Using MediaWiki 1.23.

Any hints on what to look at to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I would enable debugging in MediaWiki enable PHP warnings, then open the browser's console and network tab and look into any request made, even look at the contents replied by the server. I would use Firebug because it allows me to inspect me all relevant requests without dumping tons of windows on me. Don't make the mistake to enable the DOM tab, though - or your browser will be busy showing tons of JS deprecation warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Rainer, especially about enabling PHP warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we had an unrelated JavaScript error happening on every page. One of our site admins had added some bad script to the Common.js page in the wiki. Once I removed that script, Visual Editor began working.